# Is there an easy-to-use FTP library for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ftp

Is there a high-level Ruby library to interact with an FTP server?

Instead of Net::HTTP I can use HTTParty, Curb, Rest Client, or Typhoeus, which makes everything easier, but I can't find any similar solutions to replace/enhance Net::FTP.

More specifically, I'm looking for:

- minimal lines to connect to a server. For example, login must be explicitly specified with Net::FTP
- the ability to iterate through all entries in one folder, or using glob, or just recursively.
- the ability to get all possible information, such as the type of entry, size, mtime without manually parsing returned lines.

Comment: is there something you want to do that isn't accomplished by Net::FTP?

Comment: @Jed: no, just make it easier

Comment: Easier in what way?  Ruby's [Net::FTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/classes/Net/FTP.html) seems pretty straightforward to me...

Comment: @maerics: easier in number of lines to connect to server, recursively list files in selected folder, get info about entries without manually parsing each line of ftp.list(…)

Comment: good info, consider updating your question with these specifics and maybe it will ring a bell to someone...

Comment: I am voting to leave open because the top answer is for a library that is bundled with the Ruby language.  And because I don't care too terribly much about old questions that are off topic under the latest rules.

Comment: The short answer is that no, there isn't a decent FTP client for Ruby. FTP is an extremely under-specified protocol, where directory entries are raw text in an almost completely arbitrary format. It's a tough problem; things like Apache Commons Net  in Java iterate through parsers for every known FTP server, trying them all.

Answer (score 9):

Ruby's built-in [OpenURI](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) will handle FTP.

From OpenURI's docs:

> OpenURI is an easy-to-use wrapper for net/http, net/https and net/ftp.

This will seem to hang while it retrieves the Ruby source, but should return after a minute or two.

```
require 'open-uri'
open('ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org//pub/ruby/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.bz2') do |fi|
  File.open('ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.bz2', 'wb') do |fo|
    fo.puts fi.read
  end
end
```

---

Or [Net::FTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) is easy to use with a lot more functionality:

```
require 'net/ftp'

Net::FTP.open('ftp.ruby-lang.org') do |ftp|    
  ftp.login
  ftp.chdir('/pub/ruby')
  puts ftp.list('ruby-1.9.2*')
  puts ftp.nlst()

  ruby_file = 'ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.bz2'
  ftp.getbinaryfile(ruby_file, ruby_file, 1024)
end
```

Comment: I can't list folder contents using `open-uri`

Comment: Then use Net::FTP. I'd also look at using cURL via the Curb gem or by calling cURL using backticks.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried EventMachine? https://github.com/schleyfox/em-ftp-client