# How to download files over FTP using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, download, ftp, mechanize

I am trying to download a file over an FTP connection using the Mechanize [`download`](https://github.com/mqu/divers/blob/master/ruby/mechanize-downloader.rb) method.

I call this using:

```
agent = Mechanize.new

file = '/census_tracts_2014/file1.zip'
url = 'ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/TRACT/tl_2014_01_tract.zip'

agent.download(url,file)
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/danish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- httpclient (LoadError)
    from /Users/danish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from test.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

I think it fails because it does not recognize the `ftp2` in `ftp://ftp2.census.gov`  which I think is causing the error.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about code you wrote it really helps if it's runnable. The error doesn't match the code since it says you're trying to load "httpclient" but you don't show a require for it in your code, nor do you show the Mechanize require. It's not necessary to use Mechanize to download FTP files, OpenURI can do it nicely too. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5025280/128421

Answer (score 0):

I see this line in the error:

```
cannot load such file -- httpclient
```

and I believe `httpclient` is a gem, so you should run:

```
gem install httpclient
```

or put it in your Gemfile, then place

```
require 'httpclient'
```

at the top of your script.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the problem. It turns out I was missing both the httpclient gem and the progressbar gem. I ran the script again, however, now it just hangs, without throwing an error. Why is that?